# Ordering for has_many :through when updating

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, has-many-through

*EDIT: Revamped question*

Ok, I got a basic rails has_many :through association:

```
class SuiteEntry < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :suite
  belongs_to :case
end

class Suite < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suite_entries
  has_many :cases, :through => :suite_entries
end

class Case < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :suite_entries
  has_many :suites, :through => :suite_entries
end
```

The user now supplies through a form some cases to be stores for a given suite. My question is now: What is the best way to preserve the ordering of the cases, as the user puts them in a specific order (e.g. case1, case3, case2 - this should be stored and retrieved always in this order). When retrieving the data, the ordering the user supplied should be restored.

I'm wondering now that the best practice for storing this ordering-data:

- rely on the ordering which happens per default (e.g. by database)
- introduce a field in the join table (e.g. 'ordering')
- use some already existing plugin I dont know yet

Note: I'm using latest rails 2.3

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you are refering to the order after a database query, you can pass the ordering to the query, using a parameter, or you can order the entries in client side code (Javascript).

Comment: No, the problem is more like the following: The user supplies the Cases in an order he defines. Now the question is more on how to store this order, not how to retrieve it.

Comment: If you want to preserve the order, you need to store it in the database. So create a new field on the database and use it.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by store the ordering? You can simply add an order option to the has_many method specifying the field which should be used for ordering, e.g.

```
has_many :suite_entries, :order => "size ASC"
```

See also:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html#M001316

Comment: I've revamped my question, its about the best practice on how to store the ordering of entries in a has_many :through relation, not retrieving the elements in order